# Finding path in XML not working when in jar

Tags: java, xml, cmusphinx

I am currently having some problems. I am using an XML file to run CMU Sphinx. The XML file finds paths by using path = resource:/(file path located within resource). This works when in eclipse but when I export to runnable to jar it is unable to locate resource. What could I do to fix this? Currently I have tried adding a source folder and adding the resource contents, I unpacked the jar and everything was located where it should be. I also tried building without a source folder holding the contents. Any help would be great. Thanks :)

```
URL configURL = Transcriber.class.getResource("config.xml"); //works

ConfigurationManager cm = new ConfigurationManager(configURL); //Also works
```

From the xml

```
<property name="dictionaryPath" value="resource:/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel‌​_133Hz_6855Hz "/>
```

The above only works in eclipse but this will work in jar or eclipse

```
<property name="dictionaryPath" value="C:/project/speechcapture/resource/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel‌​_133Hz_6855Hz "/>
```

Exception in thread "main" Property exception component: 'wsjloader' property: 'location' - can't locate resource:/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel_133Hz_6855Hz

edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: Can't locate resource:/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel_133Hz_6855Hz

Comment: Is the XML file included in the jar that you export?

Comment: What directory is it in, and what is the code you're using to load it?

Comment: @Bill It is in a package called speechcapture. Both the config.xml and the resource folder are located in it (speech capture). I am currently using java to load it. If I hard code the path it works as well. (sorry should have mentioned that)

Comment: Please post the lines of code you're using to load it.

Comment: @Bill I just added the code directly involved with the problem

Comment: If system can't find the file it usually means that the file is not in the jar. It might be that you have a typo in the name or something like that. Post the contents of the jar which you can get with `jar tf jar-file`. Provide the exact exception text you are receiving, probably it's different issue.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I just posted the error I am getting. Also, if there was a typo wouldn't it throw the same exception in eclipse? As for the table it was too long to put on here but edu/cmu/sphinx is apart of it. I did also extract the jar to double check.

Comment: Hm, but in your message it says it looks for resource:/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel_133Hz_6855Hz with HUB4 in part while in your xml part you reference only resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic. Which means you have some other reference to HUB4... in some other part of the config.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I'm sorry I had shortened it in the code provided because I had to write it by hand. It is listed as resource:/speechcapture/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/HUB4_8GAU_13dcep_16k_40mel‌​_133Hz_6855Hz in the config file. (I will adjust the above code)

Comment: Please, add the output of `jar tf <your jar>` in the post. What is the version of sphinx4 you are using? Where did you get it?

Comment: Looks like you messed with paths, now you have dictionaryPath in config which is wrong. Most likely there is a typo somewhere too, so provide tf output as well as provide your config file. If you don't want to mess with config, you can use latest API version which doesn't require XML configuration from here: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4. Btw, this latest code allows you to use en-us generic acoustic model which is more accurate than HUB4.